# Расширенные функции DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Наткнулся на такую вещь как список внутри элемента списка.

> [image: Скрытый список]

> [image: Открытый список]

По результатом поиска, не нашел возможности реализации этого функционала базовыми методами.
Вопрос, есть ли возможность простой реализации этой функции? Без работы с графикой отрисовкой и прочего?

Comment: Единственное что нашел, это платные библиотеки разработки по типу "syncfusion" или "devexpress", но они платные, и не доступны в РФ.

Comment: Может это какие-то продвинутые контролы от DevExpress или там Teleric?

Comment: По запросу "c# winforms nested datagridview" можно что-нибудь найти. [Например](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/848637/Nested-DataGridView-in-Windows-Forms-Csharp)